# How to trigger another route when REST Endpoint is called in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl, control-bus

I have a scenario when I call one endpoint the another route should execute and return the result.
Lets say I have an endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/customer
```

I am using the camel-jetty to start the above servlet endpoint, like:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8080/api/customer").to("controlbus:route?routeId=route2&action=start");
```

When I do GET request on this endpoint it will trigger another route defined as below:

```
from("paho://Properties").to("jsonata://some path").routeId("route2").noAutoStratup().log("Data : ${body}");
```

I tried to use camel-controlbus but it is not working.

How can I achieve this scenario?
Can somebody please help me in this regard?

Comment: I recommend using the [Direct component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/direct-component.html). `from(...).to(direct("myRouteName"));`, `from(direct("myRouteName"))...`.

Comment: I tried but the datasource i.e. paho retrieves data using "from" only, how could I define the paho endpoint in direct ? i.e. from(rest).to(direct:datasource); from(direct:datasource).to(..);  As I am confused here. I also checked the provided link by you and it doesn't give information using direct with routeName.

Comment: `direct` is a separate endpoint. We'd need to restructure the application. `paho` reads from MQTT and "does things". To restructure, we would separate-out what has to be done in both routes (i.e. the http-route and the mqtt-route) in a `direct` route

Comment: Thanks for the response :)
As I am new in camel and still learning, could you please give an example of what you are saying?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [This tutorial over at `tutorialspoint.com`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_camel/apache_camel_quick_guide.htm) has some examples. I have no examples I can share at hand.